# Keep track of threads that have accessed an object - Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

I am currently learning multithreading in Java. I am trying to code the following problem:

*A teacher will write a text on the whiteboard. Once the text is written, the teacher thread will notify all the student threads to read the text. The students thread will notify the teach once all of them have read the text. The teacher will then proceed to write another text and the process continues until the teacher writes "end". At this point, all the threads should terminate and the program should exit.*

The suggested solution is below:

```
class WhiteBoard
{
String text;
int numberOfStudents=0;
int count=0;
public void attendance()
{
numberOfStudents++;
}

    synchronized public void write(String t)
    {
        System.out.println("Teacher is Writing " +t);
        while(count!=0)
                try{wait();}catch(Exception e){}
        text=t;
        count=numberOfStudents;
        notifyAll();
    
    }
    synchronized public String read()
    {
        
        while(count==0)
                try{wait();}catch(Exception e){}
            
        String t=text;
        count--;
        if(count==0)
                notify();
        return t;
    }

}
class Teacher extends Thread
{
WhiteBoard wb;

    String notes[]={"Java is language","It is OOPs","It is Platform Independent","It supports Thread","end"};
    
    public Teacher(WhiteBoard w)
    {
        wb=w;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<notes.length;i++)
            wb.write(notes[i]);
    }          

}

class Student extends Thread
{
String name;
WhiteBoard wb;
public Student(String n,WhiteBoard w)
{
name=n;
wb=w;
}

    public void run()
    {
        String text;
        wb.attendance();
                
        do
        {
            text=wb.read();
            System.out.println(name + " Reading " + text);
            System.out.flush();
        }while(!text.equals("end"));
    }

}

public class SCThread2
{
public static void main(String\[\] args)
{
WhiteBoard wb=new WhiteBoard();
Teacher t=new Teacher(wb);

        Student s1=new Student("A",wb);
        Student s2=new Student("B",wb);
        Student s3=new Student("C",wb);
        Student s4=new Student("D",wb);
        
        t.start();
        
        s1.start();
        s2.start();
        s3.start();
        s4.start();
        
    }   

}
```

The drawback of this solution is that it doesn't prevent the same student thread from reading the same text multiple times and I am ending up with the following output:

```
Teacher is Writing Java is language
Teacher is Writing It is OOPs
Teacher is Writing It is Platform Independent
D Reading Java is language
B Reading Java is language
B Reading It is OOPs < Repeating
C Reading Java is language
C Reading It is OOPs
Teacher is Writing It supports Thread
D Reading It is OOPs
B Reading It is OOPs < Repeating
B Reading It is Platform Independent
B Reading It is Platform Independent
D Reading It is Platform Independent
C Reading It is Platform Independent
Teacher is Writing end
C Reading It supports Thread < Repeating
D Reading It supports Thread
B Reading It supports Thread
C Reading It supports Thread < Repeating
D Reading end
B Reading end
C Reading end
A Reading Java is language
A Reading end
```

I tried the following solution to enforce that the same thread doesn't read the same text multiple times but all my threads are ending up in waiting state.

```
import static java.lang.Thread.currentThread;

class WhiteBoard {
    String text;
    int numberOfStudents = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String[] names;

    public void attendance() {numberOfStudents++;}
    synchronized public void arrayInit() {
        names = new String[numberOfStudents];
    }
    synchronized public boolean hasRead(Thread t, int length) {
        String name = t.getName();
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(names[i] == name) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        register(currentThread());
        return false;
    }
    synchronized public void register(Thread t) {
        String name = t.getName();
        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if(names[i] == null) {
                names[i] = name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    synchronized public void write(String text) {
        while (count != 0) {
            try {wait();} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        }
        System.out.println("Teacher is writing " + text);
        this.text = text;
        count = numberOfStudents;
        notifyAll();
    }
    synchronized public String read() {
        boolean hasRead = hasRead(currentThread(), count);
        while(count == 0 || hasRead == true) {
            try {wait();} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        }
        String t = text;
        count--;
        if(count == 0) {
            arrayInit();
            notify();
        }
        return t;
    }
}

class Teacher extends Thread {
    WhiteBoard w;
    String[] notes = {"Java is language", "It is OOPs", "It is platform independent", "It supports Thread", "end"};
    public Teacher(WhiteBoard w) {
        this.w = w;
    }
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            w.write(notes[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Student extends Thread {
    WhiteBoard w;
    String name;
    public Student (WhiteBoard w, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.w = w;
        this.name = name;
        w.attendance();
    }
    public void run() {
        String text;
        do {
            text = w.read();
            System.out.println(name + " Reading " + text);
            System.out.flush();
        } while (!text.equals("end"));
    }
}

public class SCThread2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WhiteBoard w = new WhiteBoard();

        Teacher t = new Teacher(w);

        Student s1 = new Student(w, "John");
        Student s2 = new Student(w,"Jonny");
        Student s3 = new Student(w, "Janardan");

        w.arrayInit();

        t.start();

        s1.start();
        s2.start();
        s3.start();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
```

and then you can change the variable from the running Thread

declare atomic boolean:

```
AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
```

Use it inside run() thread:

```
     public void run() {
        while (running.get()) {
       //your code here
       //when finished set Atomic boolean var to false:
       running.set(false)
       }
     }
```

In another function you can check if thread finished with:

```
running.get()
```

You can also stop the thread from outside function with running.set(false)